# How to store only the cloud image url in django?

Tags: python, django, web, url, django-urls

I am trying to display image stored in dropbox , but also want to store the image url in db and access through it !

i upload the image url via csv file as :

```
"https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AA0mW3mjmcesKPMUR6zpEkS-k1_IKjGGxOa5vfmBQrSsOmE7fO2QK5nqo8IYcJj4P5YpKZ74r4uM9OCGQygxLTYf7vyqAvCwbe9Y4-7EO9huCFLSfMFcnDL-QUAd48OEYDze-SOVR-aN7Npy0La63stvsfQrnTmPwjPiL4sHD9w7pbDYs4D2mWBfJUeyeX2mbq88FEEZvW0_dCk3_XU5zruoKy0wBSc8tATpywC_AoL-g-46IsZZUa_YLJteW3j6WN6ozAC30GuajDh0sPMKl60foiS8DtCPX06OH6vZzMCQ_GpbNQif9Qw9_KJvk80pmREClwK0tJwGYIVd-aLu7TWg2Di5BIR8dL1RY26y8ZjQ9g/p.jpeg?fv_content=true&size_mode=5https://www.dropbox.com/home/product_images/11?preview=iphone.jpg"
```

but while it is saved it becomes ,

> 

```
"https://localhost/media/https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AA0mW3mjmcesKPMUR6zpEkS-k1_IKjGGxOa5vfmBQrSsOmE7fO2QK5nqo8IYcJj4P5YpKZ74r4uM9OCGQygxLTYf7vyqAvCwbe9Y4-7EO9huCFLSfMFcnDL-QUAd48OEYDze-SOVR-aN7Npy0La63stvsfQrnTmPwjPiL4sHD9w7pbDYs4D2mWBfJUeyeX2mbq88FEEZvW0_dCk3_XU5zruoKy0wBSc8tATpywC_AoL-g-46IsZZUa_YLJteW3j6WN6ozAC30GuajDh0sPMKl60foiS8DtCPX06OH6vZzMCQ_GpbNQif9Qw9_KJvk80pmREClwK0tJwGYIVd-aLu7TWg2Di5BIR8dL1RY26y8ZjQ9g/p.jpeg?fv_content=true&size_mode=5https://www.dropbox.com/home/product_images/11?preview=iphone.jpg"
```

it adds localhost url infront , so it is not displayed in the page , how to deal with this?

Comment: Show us your related code!

Comment: <img
                      src="{{product.imageUrl}}"
                      class="card-img-top"
                      alt=""
                      
                    />

Comment: That's all your code?

Comment: @KlausD.  i just want to see how can i store only the base image url in db!

Comment: Add all code and information that is required to reproduce the problem to the question by editing it!